# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework insert to many-to-many table using MultiSelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have 3 tables:

**Poll:**

```
public int PollId { get; set; }
public string PollTitle { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Party> Parties { get; set; }
```

**Party**

```
public int PartyId { get; set; }
public string PartyName { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Poll> Polls { get; set; }
```

**PartiesInPoll** (both primary keys)

```
 * int PartyId
 * int PollId
```

**In my PollController:**

```
private VoterEntities db = new VoterEntities();

//
        // GET: /Polls/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.PartyId = new MultiSelectList(db.Parties, "PartyId", "PartyName");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Polls/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Poll poll)
        {

            //var parti = db.Parties.Find(partyId);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var pList = new List<Party>();
                foreach (var pId in "PartyId")
                {
                    pList.Add(new Party
                    {
                        PartyId = pId
                    });
                }
                poll.Parties = pList;
                db.Polls.Add(poll);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.PartyId = new MultiSelectList(db.Parties, "PartyId", "PartyName", poll.Parties);
            return View(poll);
        }
```

**My view:**

```
@model VoterMVC.Models.Poll

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PollTitle)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PollTitle)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PollTitle)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Parties)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.ListBox("PartyId")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Parties)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Now most of this work like a charm, but the foreach loop doesn't. It won't communicate with the views ListBox of Parties selected, and the loop adds 7(?!) new rows to the Party table and to the PartiesInPoll table.
So what I want is of course to let the values selected from the ListBox from the view, to be sent through the foreach loop, so the PartiesInPoll table gets updated.
I don't want new parties to be added to the Party table!!

Hope you got my point.
Been stuck on this for a couple of days now, any help highly appreciated, Thanks!

Edit:
If there are any better solutions for this, please spit it out :)

Comment: Take a look at `SimpleMembership Tables` look through `Membership and Roles then see how UsersInRoles`. try and `Seed` data if you are have `Migration enabled`

Answer (score 0):

This code looks wrong:

```
 foreach (var pId "PartyId")
```

It shouldn't even compile. Probably you have

```
foreach (var pId in "PartyId")
```

And this code iterates over the characters in  "PartyId" string. And there happen to be exactly 7 of them.

Comment: yes, my mistake when i pasted..! It's correct in my original code. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Once you select a `PartyId` from the listbox the view sends only this id to the post method. The for loop becomes useless in that case. Most of your problems are coming of your many-to-many relationship in database. Read more about this [here](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9922/~/understanding-and-creating-many-to-many-relationships-in-filemaker-pro). If you want to have many Parties in one Poll create 1 to * (or * to 1) relationship and you will find that for much easier way to do it.